# How can I read in multiple text files and merge them together based on Timestamps in the filename

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a folder that contains lots of text files that each contain 6 headers along with the data I'm looking to read in:

```
Phone timestamp;sensor timestamp [ns];channel 0;channel 1;channel 2;ambient
2021-02-15T12:37:32.401;536755331722174808;485232;501982;494303;16818;
2021-02-15T12:37:32.408;536755331729573094;485244;501970;494199;16770;
2021-02-15T12:37:32.415;536755331736971380;485235;502069;494234;16735;
```

The file names are in the format 'Data_20210213_120806', `Data_ YYMMDD_HHMMSS`. Currently I have just been reading the data in manually using `uigetfile` and selecting the files in the correct order (Earliest date -> latest date) and joining each file together.

This is fine when I only have a few files to look at but not very practical when lots of files are present. I'm wondering is there a way to automatically read each file in (in the correct order based on the date in the file name) and merge them into one N *-by-* 6 Matrix.

Code for manually reading in the data:

```
[filename1,pathname1] = uigetfile('*.txt','Please Choose the file to process');
filepath1 = fullfile(pathname1,filename1);
fileCell1= readcell(filepath1,'FileType','text','Delimiter',';');

% Define Structure.
Table = cell2table(fileCell1(2:end, :), 'VariableNames', fileCell1(1, :));

% Convert to Datetime
Table.("Phone timestamp") = datetime(strrep(Table.("Phone timestamp"), 'T', ' '));
```

How can I automate this process?

Comment: Do you truly want a 6-by-N table, i.e. a MATLAB [`table()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) format with 6 rows and N columns? Looking at the contents of your file you'd rather use N-by-6, i.e. 6 *columns*, and possibly, when converting the date to a `datenum` a simple numeric matrix, rather than a full-fledged `table()`.

Comment: Yea I think you're right , a numeric N-by-6 matrix is probably the best method to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reading process of text files from a folder can be done by using a loop and retrieving all the `.txt` text file names using the `dir()` function. An example merging process can be shown if the contents of a sample text file can be provided.

```
clc;

%Grabbing all the text files in a folder named "Text Files"%
Folder_Name = 'Text Files';
%Asterisk, * used to indicate any prefix/wildcard is allowed%
Text_Files = dir(fullfile(Folder_Name,'*txt'));
File_Names = {Text_Files.name}.';

Date_Num_Representation = zeros(1,length(File_Names));

Format = 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS';
for File_Index = 1: length(Text_Files)
    Name = erase(File_Names(File_Index),"Data_");
    Name = erase(Name,".txt");
    Name = char(strrep(Name,"_"," "));
    Name = Name(1:4) + "-" + Name(5:6) + "-" + Name(7:8) + Name(9:11) + ":" + Name(12:13) + ":" + Name(14:end);
    Date_Num_Representation(File_Index) = datenum(Name,Format);
end

[~,Indices] = sort(Date_Num_Representation);

Combined_Table = [];
for File_Index = 1: length(Text_Files)
Sorted_Index = Indices(File_Index);
Path = fullfile(Folder_Name,Text_Files(Sorted_Index).name);
New_Table = readtable(Path);
New_Table = New_Table(:,1:6);
Combined_Table = [Combined_Table; New_Table];
end

Combined_Table.Properties.VariableNames = {'Phone timestamp','sensor timestamp [ns]','channel 0','channel 1','channel 2','ambient'};
Combined_Table

%Might be useful%
%Combined_Table = table2cell(Combined_Table);%
```

Comment: Exactly what I'd have done, kudos. One small thing: you'll want to somehow ensure that the time-stamps are processed correctly. Windows has this irritable thing that numbers are stored alphabetically, rather than numerically (`1 11 2 21 3 31` etc). You could simply grab the date/time part of the file name, convert to a `datenum`, sort that, then read the files in that order.

Comment: Thanks very much, seems to be working well. Is there a way to merge each iteration of the file together within the for loop? I'm thinking this might not be the most efficient way and might case matlab to run very slowly but I can't think of another way to do it. 

Ie: Final_File = [file1; file2; file3...file(length(Text_files))];

Comment: This should hopefully take care of the sorting, I haven't been able to test if the sorting on Windows as the sorting on my machine is done numerically for suffixes.